# Count number of Attempts made using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a POCO as under

```
public class Test
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public int? Bucket { get; set; }
    public string AgreementId { get; set; }
    public string DispositionCode { get; set; }
}
```

with some test data

```
List<Test> lsttest = new List<Test>();
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "1", Bucket = 0, DispositionCode = "PR", Region = "Region1" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "1", Bucket = 0, DispositionCode = "PTP", Region = "Region1" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "2", Bucket = 0, DispositionCode = "PTP", Region = "Region1" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "2", Bucket = 0, DispositionCode = "PTP", Region = "Region2" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "12", Bucket = 10, DispositionCode = "RNGN", Region = "Region2" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "12", Bucket = 10, DispositionCode = "ABT", Region = "Region2" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "12", Bucket = 10, DispositionCode = "WN", Region = "Region2" });
lsttest.Add(new Test { AgreementId = "12", Bucket = 10, DispositionCode = "ABT", Region = "Region2" });
```

what I am looking for is the below output

```
Region = "Region1", Bucket = 0, Attempt1 = 1,Attempt2 = 2,Attempt3=0, AttemptMoreThan3=0
Region = "Region2", Bucket = 0, Attempt1 = 1,Attempt2 = 0,Attempt3=0, AttemptMoreThan3=0
Region = "Region2", Bucket = 10, Attempt1 = 0,Attempt2 = 0,Attempt3=0, AttemptMoreThan3=4
```

As can be figure out,

```
 For AgreementId = "1" Bucket = 0 Region = "Region1", there are 2 DispositionCodes. So the AttemptCount = 2
 For AgreementId = "2" Bucket = 0 Region = "Region1", there is 1 DispositionCode. So the AttemptCount = 1
 For AgreementId = "2" Bucket = 0 Region = "Region2", there is 1 DispositionCode. So the AttemptCount = 1
 For AgreementId = "12" Bucket = 10 Region = "Region2", there are 4 DispositionCodes. So the AttemptCount = 4
```

The Output dataPacket looks as under

```
public class TestOutput
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public int? Bucket { get; set; }
    public int Attempt1 { get; set; }
    public int Attempt2 { get; set; }
    public int Attempt3 { get; set; }
    public int AttemptMoreThan3 { get; set; }

}
```

My attempt so far stands

```
var groupByRegionBucket = lsttest
                          .GroupBy(x => new { x.Region, x.Bucket, x.AgreementId })
                          .Select(y => new
                          {
                              Region = y.Key.Region,
                              Bucket = y.Key.Bucket,
                              AgreementId = y.Key.AgreementId,
                              DispositionCode = y.Count()
                          })                                  
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Explain `Attempt1`, `Attempt2`, and `Attempt3` a little more. I can see your counting of `DispositionCodes`, yet it dont see how the results relate to them clearly

Comment: @Michael, based on the disposition codes count made for the AgreementId's  grouped by Region and Bucket, the Attempt counts are made.

Comment: So if there were 3 *disposition codes* would would the attempts equal

Comment: Attemptcount = 3. If Count Of dispositioncode =1 then Attempt Count = 1, If Count Of dispositioncode > 3, then AttemptCount should be more than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved as under

```
var groupByRegionBucketForAttempts = lsttest
                                  .Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.DispositionCode))
                                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Region, x.Bucket, x.AgreementId })
                                  .Select(y => new
                                  {
                                      Region = y.Key.Region,
                                      Bucket = y.Key.Bucket,
                                      AgreementId = y.Key.AgreementId,
                                      DispositionCode =  y.Count(),
                                      Attempts = 
                                      y.Count() == 1? "Attempt1": 
                                      y.Count() == 2 ? "Attempt2" :
                                      y.Count() == 3 ? "Attempt3" : "Attempt>3"
                                  })
                                  .ToList();

            var attemptsQuery = groupByRegionBucketForAttempts
                    .GroupBy(c => new { c.Region, c.Bucket })
                    .Select(g => new {
                        Region = g.Key.Region,
                        Bucket = g.Key.Bucket,
                        Attempt1 = g.Where(x => x.Attempts == "Attempt1").Sum(x => x.DispositionCode),
                        Attempt2 = g.Where(x => x.Attempts == "Attempt2").Sum(x => x.DispositionCode),
                        Attempt3 = g.Where(x => x.Attempts == "Attempt3").Sum(x => x.DispositionCode),
                        AttemptMoreThan3 = g.Where(x => x.Attempts == "Attempt>3").Sum(x => x.DispositionCode)

                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var groupByRegionBucket = lsttest
                          .GroupBy(x => new { x.Region, x.Bucket, x.AgreementId })
                          .Select(y => new TestOutput
                          {
                              Region = y.Key.Region,
                              Bucket = y.Key.Bucket,
                              Attempt1 = y.Count() == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                              Attempt2 = y.Count() == 2 ? 2 : 0,
                              Attempt3 = y.Count() == 3 ? 3 : 0,
                              AttemptMoreThan3 = y.Count() > 3 ? y.Count() : 0,
                          })
                          .ToList()
                          .GroupBy(z => new { z.Region })
                          .Select(z1 => new TestOutput
                          {
                              Region = z1.Key.Region,
                              Bucket = z1.Sum(a => a.Bucket),
                              Attempt1 = z1.Sum(a => a.Attempt1),
                              Attempt2 = z1.Sum(a => a.Attempt2),
                              Attempt3 = z1.Sum(a => a.Attempt3),
                              AttemptMoreThan3 = z1.Sum(a => a.AttemptMoreThan3),
                          }).ToList();
```